# How can i run my python program in DJANGO

Tags: python, django, web-scraping, django-rest-framework

I have python script of web scraping that fetch given name song from youtube and give me output as in JSON format. it has many field like url,title,thumnail,duration and artist and all these field are stores in JSON file. SO i want to add that script in Django views.py, So how can i implement this.

[Here is the picture of output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XL4DD.png)

Comment: better paste json as example instead of pasting screenshot of it ;) that might be useful in future, more self-contained, easier to be indexed, searchable, etc.

Comment: `want to add that script in Django views.py, So how can i implement this.` provide a better description of your need in terms of business (UX) logic. You will get more accurate answers afterwards

Comment: it will be cool if you eventually present also the content of your script responsible for fetching that data from YT.

Answer (score 0):

first use your requests then put it in context then return it after all use your current context into html file

Answer (score 0):

You can copy your python file to the project Django folder, where `__init__.py` is.

If your file name is `index.py`. Then in you can include the file using `from .index import *`